# Computing the number of elements in a finite field $F$

Tags: abstract-algebra

a) If $F$ is a splitting field of the polynomial $x^4 + 1$ over $\mathbb{Z}_7$

b) If $F$ is the minimal extension of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ in which every polynomial $f \in \mathbb{Z}_3[x]$ of degress 2 has a root.

Everything I see in my notes involves a polynomial of the form $x^{p^n} -x$.  There is nothing involving $x^{p^n} -1$ so I am a little lost on part a. I know that $F$ is an extension of $\mathbb{Z}_7$ where $x^4 + 1$ decomposes into linear factors such that $x^4 + 1 = c \prod _{i=1}^{4} ( X - a_i)$ where $c \in \mathbb{Z}_7$ and for each $i, (X-a_i) \in F$. **EDIT:** I actually see now that a field $\mathbb{F}_q, q=p^n$ is always a simple extension of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ by a root of some irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{Z}_p$ so I guess my question would be is $x^4 + 1$ irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_7$?
For part b, I want consider all polynomials of degree 2 with coeffients of 0,1,2 that have a root, i.e are reducible.  I've tried to go about this by finding them and there were quite a few so I'm guessing finding them isn't necesary.  I think this has someting to do with quadratic non-residues, but I could be wrong.

Comment: a) $x^4+1=\Phi_8(x)$ and the splitting fields of cyclotomic polynomials are always straightforward to find. $8\mid(7^2-1)$, hence the splitting field if $\mathbb{F}_{49}$, which has... $49$ elements.

Comment: b) Every quadratic polynomial in $\mathbb{F}_3[x]$ completely factors over $\mathbb{F}_9$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio You use $7^2 -1$ because $x^2-1$ is a factor of $x^4 + 1$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio And how do you know that for b?  Just by brute force?

Comment: $x^2-1$ is not a factor of $x^4+1$, but $x^4+1$ is the eighth cyclotomic polynomial, hence it is enough to find the smallest $k$ such that $7^k-1$ is a multiple of $8$.

Comment: b) simply follows from the very definition of $\mathbb{F}_{p^2}$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Not sure I've ever heard of cyclotomic polynomials, but I'll look into it.  Thank you

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Is there a way to do this without using the fact that $x^4+1$ is a cyclotomic polynomial because I really can't find anything about it in my notes at all

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Could you explain b a little more please?  I don't see how it follows from the definition